# MediaPicker field to MediaLibraryPicker migration in Orchard CMS

Tags: migration, media, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

We used to have this mediapicker field for thumbnails of a specific Content Type.

Old placement entry (1.6):

```
Fields_MediaPicker-Thumbnail="ImageArea:1"
```

[image]

New placement (1.7.1 after migration):

```
Fields_MediaLibraryPicker-Thumbnail="ImageArea:1"
```

[image]

The ones above basically render it in a zone called ImageArea. In the old version, media picker just rendered the image itself. In 1.7, it now renders the field title, filename and image.

Is there a way to specify to only render the image via placement without changing the template? Or is creating an alternate for medialibrarypicker field a better alternative?

Comment: You will have to create an alternate, or use CSS to hide the title and filename

Comment: Appreciate your speedy reply @Hazza. Yeah, was thinking of an alternate. Don't really wanna do the css/template change route since it's not only on one page / content type. I've got a lot of these all over my site. The path of least resistance/change would be best.

Comment: Yeah ^_^ But one alternate should suffice for all your pages and content types. Or a few lines in your themes css (this may not be possible, not sure what the html of the media library picker view looks like). But it is frustrating you have to create it for every theme you do ^_^ be a rebel, edit the core ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the parts of the Image that you don't want to display in placement.info :

```
<Match ContentType="Image">
<Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
<Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
<Place Parts_Title_Summary="-"/>  
</Match>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just commited a change on the 1.7.X branch to be able to display the MediaLibraryPickerField in Summary :
https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19952